# Patch - How to check that a patched class's instance called a class function?

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I'm trying to patch a class, have a function under test create an instance of the patched class, have that instance call a class function, then I want to test that that class function was called. How can I do this?

Below is the basic variation of my code:

The test file:

```
class TestChannel(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("notification.models.Channel")
    def testAddChannelWithNamePutsChannel(self, *args):
        addChannelWithName("channel1")
        self.assertTrue(Channel.put.called)
```

The code to be tested:

```
def addChannelWithName(name):
    channel = Channel(name = name)
    channel.put()
```

Basically, I want to test that channel.put() was called. Of course this code doesn't work because I'm checking if the class function put() is being called not for the instance, but in general. I need to call it on the instance for it to pass. I've tried several variations of mocking different parts of the Channel class and it's return values, but I can't seem to get it to work. How might I do this? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making your addChannelWithName function returns the Channel instance ?

```
def addChannelWithName(name):
    channel = Channel(name = name)
    channel.put()
    return channel

class TestChannel(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("notification.models.Channel")
    def testAddChannelWithNamePutsChannel(self, *args):
        channel = addChannelWithName("channel1")
        self.assertTrue(channel.put.called)
```

Comment: That works in this case and I'll give you a +1 for that. However, I also have a very similar function that deletes a channel, and in that case trying to return the deleted object doesn't make much sense. Any idea that would work in all cases?

Comment: I'd have to know much more about your `Channel` class and what "deleting a channel" means (implie, do, whatever) etc to answer this one. One point is that unit testing requires testable code... and it's easier to write testable code when you write the code first ;)